# Pronunciation of Ketuba text

Tags: product-recommendation, pronunciation, ketubah, transliteration

Can anyone recommend a source for the text of the Ketuba including nekudot, a transliteration, or a recording that could be used as a guide for pronunciation?

Answer (score 7):

The [RCA Madrich (rabbi's handbook) by Rabbi Reuven P. Bulka](http://www.eichlers.com/rca-lifecycle-madrich.html) has it vowelized.

Answer (score 6):

https://archive.org/details/ReadingKesubah has an mp3 audio recording of it.

Answer (score 3):

Nit'ey Gavriel nesuin part 1 page 344.  http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46545&pgnum=344

Has it with nekudot with commentaries (one of the commentaries explains why he decided to put these nekudot)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the transliteration of the ketubah. I have chosen to use the Modern Israeli pronunciation, as it is very common and somewhat "universal" among Jews of all backgrounds. To those who are more familiar with the ketubah text than me, please check and see if I missed anything or made a mistake. For reference, I used the text that [hazoriz provided in his answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/67213/11486) from Nitaei Gavriel.

> B'ezrat Hashem Yitbarech
>
> B'.... bashabat ..... yom l'chodesh .... sh'nat chameshet alafim ush'va me'ot .... livri'at olam l'minyan she'anu monin kan ir ..... ech habachur .... ben moha''ra .... amar lah l'hada b'tulta .... bat moha''ra .... hevei li l'intu k'dat Moshe v'Yisra'el va'ana eflach v'okir v'eizun va'afarnes yatichi lichi k'hilchot guvrin y'huda'in d'falchin umokrin v'zanin um'farn'sin linseihon b'kushta vihivna lichi mohar b'tulaichi k'saf zuzei matan d'chazei lichi mid'oraita um'zonaichi uch'sutaichi v'sipukaichi umei'al l'vatichi k'orach kol ar'a utz'vi'at marat .... b'tulta da vahavat leih l'intu, v'den n'dunya d'han'alat leih mibei avu'ah  bein b'chesef bein b'zahav bein b'tachshitin b'manei dilvusha b'shimushei dirah uv'shimusha d'arsa, hakol kibel alav moha''ra .... chatan d'nan b'me'ah z'kukim kesef tzaruf v'tzavei moha''ra .... chatan d'nan v'hosif lah min dileih od me'ah z'kukim kesef tzaruf acherim k'negdan sach hakol matayim z'kukim kesef tzaruf v'chach amar moha''ra .... chatan d'nan acharayut s'tar k'tubta da n'dunya den v'tosefta da kablit alai v'al yartai batrai l'hitpara mikol s'far arag nichsin v'kinyanin d'it li t'chot kol sh'maya diknai v'da'atid ana l'miknei nichsin d'it l'hon acharayut ud'leit l'hon acharayut kulhon y'hon achara'in v'arva'in lifro'a minhon sh'tar k'tubta da n'dunya den v'tosefta da mina'i va'afilu min g'lima d'al katfai b'chayai uvatar chayai min yoma d'nan ul'alam v'acharayut (v'chomer) sh'tar k'tubta da n'dunya den v'tosefta da kibel alav moha''ra ....chatan d'nan k'chomer kol sh'tarei k'tubot v'toseftot d'nahagin bivnat Yisra'el ha'asuyin k'tikun chachameinu zichronam livrachah, d'la k'asmachta ud'la k'tofsei dishtarei uk'neina min moha''ra .... ben moha''ra .... chatan d'nan l'marat .... bat moha''ra .... b'tulta da k'chol mah d'chatuv um'forash l'eil b'mana d'chasar l'miknaya beih hakol sharir v'kayam
>
> N'um .... ed
>
> N'um .... ed