# Where can I find a transliteration of the ketubah text?

Tags: aramaic, ketubah, transliteration

Is there a transliteration of the ketubah text anywhere?  My Aramaic is a little rusty.
Thanks so much!

Comment: Do you mean _translation_?

Comment: http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/465168/jewish/The-Marriage-Contract-Ketubah.htm

Comment: See also audio: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40422/21