# May a Ketubah be vowelized?

Tags: halacha, ketubah, vowels-nekudot

[Here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40422/pronunciation-of-ketuba-text) is a source where the ketubah is vowelized. Would a vowelized ketubah be halachically valid?

Comment: Why would it be invaild?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, rishon. I'd like to second @sam's question: why would a ktuba with vowels be invalid? Please consider [edit]ing in your motivation for the question, and reasoning behind it. Thanks! Hope you enjoy Mi Yodeya, and if you're looking for more stuff to read, why not start with our other ~35 [tag:ketubah] questions.

Answer (score 1):

When the Cairo Genizah were discovered, there were many kethuboth found, and some of them were vowelized when a word had an odd spelling, and certain letters would have a line above or below them to signify hard or soft letters for pronunciation guides.

Comment: But then again there was also a round tefillin shel yad found - clearly something that did not go with halacha. So can we really rely on the Cairo Genizah? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tefillin#Manufacture_and_contents

Answer (score 0):

this question was posed to [The Institute for Dayanim](http://www.din.org.il/2014/06/24/%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%91%D7%94-%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%AA/) and they wrote back saying that it's okay for a Kesubah to be voweled.

האם מותר לכתוב כתובה מנוקדת?

תשובה:

שלום רב.

כן. אין כל בעיה בכתובה מנוקדת.