# Kesubah with vowels

Tags: internet, ketubah

I have been asked to read the kesubah at a wedding in two days. Can someone point me to a copy of the kesubah WITH vowels (preferably online)?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Ian. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Note there are subtle variations out there of the text, so best to verify what text they are using exactly if you want to be best prepared

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46545&pgnum=344) is a link from the Nitaei Gavriel with the Ketubah vowelized. I also provided transliteration of the Ketubah text based on the previous link [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/93253/11486).